# How do I get my Swift code to read a specific piece of information from the JSON file

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to read the data for "Name" in a JSON file I am hosting using Swift and I seem to only be able to read the whole JSON file and not able to pick out specific data. My JSON file contains this:

```
[{"Email":"Admin@admin.com","Password":"password","Name":"Admin"}]
```

The swift code I am using is this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //to get data from external DB

    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/Projects/Test_mobileAPI/test_userInfo.php?email=Admin@admin.com")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Error Occured")
        }
        else{
            print("Okie")
            if let content = data {
                do{
                    //Array
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print("this part works")
                    print(myJson)
                    if let diction = myJson as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        if let name = myJson["Name"]{
                            print(name as Any)
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

The output I keep getting is this:

```
Okie
this part works
(
        {
        Email = "Admin@admin.com";
        Name = Admin;
        Password = password;
    }
)
```

But I do not get just the value for "Name". Can anyone help me get the value for "Name" (i.e "Admin")

Comment: FYI - Do not use `mutableContainers` option in Swift. Do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use a Swift dictionary.

Comment: Please learn to read JSON. `[ ]` means array. `{ }` means dictionary.

Comment: @rmaddy [OT] You stole my *learn to read* phrase  But I give you a lifetime license for free.

Comment: @vadian Sorry, didn't know you had the copyright. :)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try

```
if  let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content) as? [[String:Any]] {
   if let first = myJson.first {
      print(first["Name"])
   }
}
```

Comment: @Sh_Khab Thanks, that seems to work, I'll try developing further and get back to you, but it seems to have worked

Comment: i think no need for the array just make it **{"Email":"Admin@admin.com","Password":"password","Name":"Admin"}** as a dictionary

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the JSON that you're receiving back *isn't* a Dictionary, it's a single element array with a dictionary in it. So when you do

```
if let diction = myJson as? NSDictionary
```

the myJson object is failing the cast to NSDictionary.  If you unwrap the array first, you should then be able to reference the dictionary and pick off any keyed values you want:

```
                if let array = myJson as? NSArray
                {
                     if let myDict = array[0] as? NSDictionary
                     {
                         if let name = myDict ["Name"]{
                             print(name as Any)
                         }
                      }
                }
```

Comment: Not my vote but you should not use `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use Swift arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: How do I make it a dictionary then? @Chris Allwein

Comment: @JonathanLamptey Either unwrap the array first, as shown in my sample code, or have your server emit JSON without wrapping it in an array.  [ ] denotes a json array.  { } denotes a dictionary.